# create dataframe from columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe df which contains a column `check_r2` which contains values either `True` or `False`.
I want to create another dataframe `df1` which will contain rows for only those which have `check_r2` as `True`

I tried with this code but getting empty dataframe as output, I am creating this dataframe from excel, where column values are in capital i.e TRUE or FALSE but when I Print them using print(df) I get True or False as output, I tried both ways while comparing but the output was same

```
code
df = read_data()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df[df['check_r2'] =="True"]
```

also tried

```
df1 = df1.append(df[df['check_r2'] =="True"])
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the actual excel values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = df[df['check_r2'] ==True]
```

check the datatype

```
df.info()
```

```
check_r2    9 non-null bool
```

Pandas is converting it to boolean.

Comment: this worked, but arent the values suppposed to be string

Comment: Pandas is converting it to boolean.>>>> yes, will keep this in mind, thank you.

Comment: Actually, when you are storing TRUE & FALSE in excel, it is stored as a logical value. Check by =TYPE(cell number), it will return 4 which shows it is a logical value. Excel stores additional value, unlike CSV. If you want to stop pandas from interpreting on their own you can use df = pandas.read_excel("temp.xlsx", dtype={"check_r2":object}) but, in this case it will not help because pandas will use excel own implementation which is also boolean. Try saving it to CSV and using df = pandas.read_csv("temp.xlsx", dtype={"check_r2":object}), then you will see TRUE, False.